# New line increases my body.childNodes count

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to count no of elements in body, And i am doing this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Practice Javascript</title>
<script>
window.onload = count;
function count()
{ 
 var ele = document.body.childNodes;
 alert(ele.length);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Text one</p>
<p>Text Two</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting output as 2 but it was 5

But when i deleted new line by following code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Practice Javascript</title>
<script>
window.onload = count;
function count()
{ 
 var ele = document.body.childNodes;
 alert(ele.length);
}

</script>
</head>
<body><p>Text one</p><p>Text Two</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Its gives output 3
How Dom tree evaluates no of child nodes present?

Comment: A newline is a text node. So yes. The node count will go up.

Comment: You should know that text, even outside of an element tag, is still a child-node of the parent element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`childNodes` contains text nodes. Use `childElementCount` instead.
`children` on the other hand, contains no text nodes. So you could use `node.children.length`.
In your case, you have 3 new lines in that html, so 3+2 is 5.

Comment: <body><p>Textone</p><p>TextTwo</p></body> this also alerts me 3

Comment: Don't have any line breaks before html or after. They count as text nodes in the body. This works: `<body><p>Textone</p><p>TextTwo</p></body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

Like simonzack already said, the line breaks are being processed to textNodes. Thus you get 5 Nodes below the body, as you have

```
<body>
  TextNode{\n}
  ElementNode{p}
  TextNode{\n}
  ElementNode{p}
  TextNode{\n}
</body>
```

You could avoid this by removing all whitespaces and line breaks in your html, e.g.

```
<body><p>Text one</p><p>Text Two</p></body>
```

Or by using `childElementCount` as suggested.

Comment: <body><p>Textone</p><p>TextTwo</p></body> this also alerts me 3

Answer (score 0):

childNodes counts all html tags as well as normal text as separate nodes. If you have even a single space or new line between tags, they will be text nodes and counted in childNodes.

Also, you should note that childNodes is not recursive in that it will not report nodes inside the immediate child nodes.